# How to add multilingual support rewrite rules using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website urls structure is based like this

```
www.domain.com/page1 -> default language
```

where all my pages are located in the root folder.

I want to add multilingual support and create folders for each language, containing the file with the translated text.

So when a language is requested, looks in the appropriate language folder and display it.

```
www.domain.com/lang/page1 -> 2 chars language
```

How can I do this, keeping the english language as the default language?

Currently this is my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use language redirection by .htaccess. An example for German:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (de) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://google.de [L]
```

---

Why are not you just using PHP? You can get the browser language, just look at this function:

```
public static function getBrowser ($languages, $accept) {
    // HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is defined in
    // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4
    // pattern to find is therefore something like this:
    //    1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )
    // where:
    //    language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
    //    qvalue         = ( "0" [ "." 0*3DIGIT ] )
    //            | ( "1" [ "." 0*3("0") ] )
    preg_match_all("/([[:alpha:]]{1,8})(-([[:alpha:]|-]{1,8}))?" .
                   "(\s*;\s*q\s*=\s*(1\.0{0,3}|0\.\d{0,3}))?\s*(,|$)/i",
                   $accept, $hits, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    // default language (in case of no hits) is the first in the array
    $bestlang = $languages[0];
    $bestqval = 0;

    foreach ($hits as $arr) {
        // read data from the array of this hit
        $langprefix = strtolower ($arr[1]);
        if (!empty($arr[3])) {
            $langrange = strtolower ($arr[3]);
            $language = $langprefix . "-" . $langrange;
        }
        else $language = $langprefix;
        $qvalue = 1.0;
        if (!empty($arr[5])) $qvalue = floatval($arr[5]);

        // find q-maximal language
        if (in_array($language,$languages) && ($qvalue > $bestqval)) {
            $bestlang = $language;
            $bestqval = $qvalue;
        }
        // if no direct hit, try the prefix only but decrease q-value
        // by 10% (as http_negotiate_language does)
        else if (in_array($languageprefix,$languages) 
            && (($qvalue*0.9) > $bestqval)) 
        {
            $bestlang = $languageprefix;
            $bestqval = $qvalue*0.9;
        }
    }
    return $bestlang;
}
```

I use it myself with this call:

```
$browserLanguage = getBrowser($supportedLanguages, $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGES'];
```

For `$supportedLanguages`, you can use codes like `de`, `en-gb` or `en-us`.

Comment: Thank you but I want to follow the other way, that people will also allow to change the page by theirself

Comment: I am playing around with this RewriteRule ^`(nl|de)?/?(.*)$  $1.php?lang=$2 [L,QSA]` without luck

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos: I have edited my post for a solution in PHP.